# when loading items to grid it has empty grids

Tags: android, arrays, grid

While i am working on gridview i faced following problems, any help will be appreciated,

When I load data to my gridview it loads all the 18 items. (Log.i it shows all the 18 items in my LogCat because of the if condition i have used ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")) ). but it loads 10 empty grids as well. why it loads other 10 empty grids.

Since there are only 18 items belongs to the MainCategoryID=1, it should load only 18 grids, but this loads 28 grids(that is because there are 28 items inside responseJson). I want to limit it to 18 grids and remove empty grids.

when i load it looks like this
[image]

ListFragment class

```
 public class PizzaFragment extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleted {

    GridView grid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main, container, false);

        new PizzaMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();

        mQuickReturnView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer);
        mQuickReturnView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer1);
        mQuickReturnView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer2);

        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            String[] Description = new String[responseJson.length()];
            String[] ImageURL = new String[responseJson.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);
                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
                    Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("MainCategoryID"));
                    ImageURL[i] = object.getString("ImageURL");
                    Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("Description"));
                    Description[i] = object.getString("Description");

                    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), Description,
                            ImageURL);
                    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

CustomGrid class

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] Description;
    private final String[] ImageURL;

    public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] Description, String[] ImageURL) {
        this.context = c;
        this.Description = Description;
        this.ImageURL = ImageURL;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Description.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Description[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_pizza, parent, false);
            holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvHeader.setText(Description[position]);
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(ImageURL[position]).into(holder.ivImage);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private ImageView ivImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in the `getCount()` method of your CustomGrid class, you're returning the size of the `Description[]` array; and `String[] Description = new String[responseJson.length()];`, together with `CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), Description, ImageURL);` in your ListFragment class caused the grid to see 28 items (`Description[]` array's size) instead of 18 items that have `"MainCategoryID"` of `1`.

You might want to rewrite your `public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson)` method so that you only store the descriptions and image URLs for the items that match your criteria. Moreover

```
CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), Description, ImageURL);
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

can be outside of the loop, after you have your data in place already.

I went ahead and rewrite your code for you below:

```
public class PizzaFragment extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleted {
    GridView grid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main, container, false);

        new PizzaMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();

        mQuickReturnView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer);
        mQuickReturnView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer1);
        mQuickReturnView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.footer2);

        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {
        try {
            List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));

                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));

                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));

                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                }
            }

            CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), descriptions, imageUrls);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private Context mContext;
    private final List<String> descriptions;
    private final List<String> imageUrls;

    public CustomGrid(Context c, List<String> descriptions, List<String> imageUrls) {
        this.context = c;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return descriptions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return descriptions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_pizza, parent, false);
            holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvHeader.setText(descriptions.get(position));
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(imageUrls.get(position)).into(holder.ivImage);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private ImageView ivImage;
    }
}
```

Note: I switched to using `List` instead of `Array`, and fixed some code style issues. I did not test this though. You should try the example yourself and consult the documentation for more information as well. Also read [the Google Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) for good Java style guidelines.

Comment: this is a perfect answer as I wanted, thank you a lot for your answer and suggestion about the Google Java Style.